# Javascript pass window context to framework call inside function

Tags: javascript, neo4j, javascript-objects

I'm working on a Neo4j graph interface with neovis and try to outsource my code.

I plan to get all functions that the graph needs to be in the Graph() function.
I want to create a new Object with new Graph() for every Graph i'm creating.

I'm running now into the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.body.container is null` from the Neovis framework when initializing the graph.

My guess is, that the right context isn't passed correctly.

Code to initialize the graph:

```
Graph.prototype.drawGraph = function(viz){
        this.viz = viz;
        this.viz = new NeoVis.default(this.config);
        this.viz.render();
    };
```

I also tried to get it working with passing the context to the instructor and guessing around with the call() and apply() method.

Is there a way to pass the right context and get it working without changing the original code from the framework?

Edit:
Full workflow:

```
//inside of normal window context
graphs[0] = new Graph(code, this);
            graphs[0].setConfig(config);
            graphs[0].setLimit(limit);
            graphs[0].createGraphArea(result,viz);


//inside of Graph function
this.createGraphArea = function(graph_data,viz){
        //create HTML
        
        if(Number.isInteger(graph_data[0]))
            this.createGraphTable(graph_data)
        else
            this.drawGraph(viz);
    }
```

Comment: add the code where you're invoking `drawGraph`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee
where do you mean?

It's also called from within the Graph instance. The way is: 
graphs[0] = new Graph();
graphs[0].createGraphArea(result);

inside of createGraphArea the drawGraph function is called. So it would be the same problem as before.

Comment: Please update that in the question

Comment: @KunalMukherjee i updated the question and added context

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes you can do here -

Approach 1) Capture the `this` of the window, so in your graph function -

```
// Outside the graph function, in global scope (window)
var self = this;

this.createGraphArea = function(graph_data,viz){
    //create HTML
    
    if(Number.isInteger(graph_data[0]))
        self.createGraphTable(graph_data);
    else
        self.drawGraph(viz);
}
```

Approach 2) Use ES6 arrow-functions which provides lexical scoping -

```
this.createGraphArea = (graph_data,viz) => {
    //create HTML
    
    if(Number.isInteger(graph_data[0]))
        this.createGraphTable(graph_data);
    else
        this.drawGraph(viz);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i'm still getting the same error. 
I already tried approach 1 and approach 2 also doesn't seem to work. Both giving me the same error as before.